# Other than its class feature, what powers allow the battlemind to place encounter-long marks?

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind, mark

I'm trying to find out which powers allow the Battlemind to place encounter-long marks.  I know that the class feature **`Battlemind's Demand`** lets you do this to two targets, but most of the other powers only let a Battlemind mark `until the end of your next turn.`

Are there any other powers that let the Battlemind mark `until the end of the encounter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Precognitive Eye` - Daily 15 - Pg 43 Psionic Power
- `Focus Bind` - Daily 19 - Pg 45 Psionic Power
- `Iron Presence` - At Will 23 (w/Augment 6 in Close Burst 2) - Pg 46 Psionic Power

Note: `Luring Steel` - Daily 13 - 51 PHB3 - lets you use Battlemind's demand against different numbers of targets depending on augmentation.  Also `Iron Presence` without augmentation functions the same as Battlemind's Demand with augmentation.